# Add MySQL Column Comment using NHibernate Mapping File?

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there a way to add some NHibernate XML configuration node or property so that the generated create table script for MySQL will contain column comments?

A example of this kind of script is like below:

```
CREATE TABLE table_with_comments(
  column1 INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'this is the primary key.',
  column2 TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (column1)
)
```

My question is whether it is possible to put the comment inside the xml mapping file. Or if we are using NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes, is there a way to put the comment in the attribute annotation?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of adding DB specific metadata to mappings is to use [Auxiliary Database Objects](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-database-object) via the `<database-object>` tag.

Ayende Rahien also has a short [blog entry](http://ayende.com/blog/3947/nhibernate-mapping-database-object) with examples on its use.

Also the exact same question, except for Oracle, has already been asked and answered. Please see [Setting Oracle's Column COMMENTS Attribute with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796448/setting-oracles-column-comments-attribute-with-nhibernate) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So it means that I need to add some alter column add comment script in that database-object tag. But if you look at this [page](http://cornempire.net/2010/04/15/add-comments-to-column-mysql/), there is no way to write this kind of alter column SQL. Actually my question is, does NHibernate support adding comment in the Create Table script it generates? I read through the [help document](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/) but didn't find anything.

Comment: At the moment there is no way to add comments when the table is created with NHibernate. A possible alternative is to write a stored procedure taking the table name, column name and comment. The procedure could call `SHOW CREATE TABLE...` extract the information relating to the column in question and build the alter table statement around that.